# Sharing data between interceptor (plugin) and block. How?

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, plugin, interceptor

I want to use some data from intercepters in a block.

To start with I have attempted to use DI to inject a simple custom model but by logging I see that a instance is been used by the interceptor and the block.

What should I be doing to share data between the interceptor (plugin) and block given that this will always be in the same request lifecycle (i.e. not persisting between requests)?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the core registry for this purpose. Inject `Magento\Framework\Registry` into block and plug-in classes. Use it like this: `$this->coreRegistry->register('my_data', $data);` and `$data = $this->coreRegistry->registry('my_data');`

Comment: When I use ``$data = $this->coreRegistry->registry('my_data');`` from the block class I don't see the expected value. Could the type of interceptor (around) be causing an issue?

Comment: Sounds like the call to access the data is happening before the data is set. It would help if you posted your code.

Comment: From logging I see the call to ``->register('foo', 'bar')`` happens before ```->registry('foo')```. Could it be the coreRegistry is scoped?

Comment: Works very well for me - I have used it for sharing data between two plugins. Just the approach is not my favourite one, as it works like a global variable.